# How to get state of the MediaPlayer?

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player

I am doing a quick implementation of an embedded media player into my app.

Using MediaPlayer from [System.Windows.Media](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.play%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

I want to be able to enable the Play button only when:

- Media player not playing the audio file
- Media player is finishing playing it
- Media player is paused
- Media player is stopped

etc etc....

So I looked at MSDN documentation, I couldn't find anything said about getting the state of the player.  Nor the event that indicates the player is being pause/stop/play...

If this doesn't have the functionality that I want, which class I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You might find [MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement?view=net-5.0) more appropriate for what you want to do. It has, for example, a MediaEnded event.